# How to get the URI of an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I try to get the calling Intent from within a Service.
The method `Service.getIntent()` is deprecated and the method `parseUri(String uri, int flags)` is suggested as its substitute.
I do not know what to pass as the uri-string.
Where to get the URI of the Intent?

(I wonder why the method `toUri()` is suggested in the API to get the URI of an Intent you can not access yet...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to get the calling Intent from within a Service

It is passed into `onStartCommand()` and/or `onBind()`. In some cases, it is passed along to you later (e.g., `IntentService` gives you the `Intent` in `onHandleIntent()`, based on its built-in implementation of `onStartCommand()`).

If you need the `Intent` outside of those methods, it is your job to hold onto it (e.g., as part of some "job" object that represents some work that the service is executing on a background thread).

Comment: yes i saw it.. originally i wanted to access th intent outside of this methods.. would have been easier..  but now i do required work in OnStart. Thank you